# Octave error: no default value for argument 1 while calling function

Tags: matlab, octave

I need to find [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) value for each value by column.
So I have such function:

```
function [X_norm, mu, sigma] = featureNormalize(X)

X_norm = X;
mu = zeros(1, size(X, 2));
sigma = zeros(1, size(X, 2));

for x = 1:size(X, 1)
    mu(1,x) = mean(:, x)
    sigma(1,x) = std(:, x)
    for y = 1:size(X, 2)  
        X_norm(x,y) = (X(x,y) - mu)/sigma
    end  
end    

end
```

And I`m trying to call this function this way:

```
>> X = [23 32 2 ; 23 23 1];
>> featureNormalize(X)
```

As a result I get such error: *no default value for argument 1 while calling function.* I can't get what it's wrong here, any suggestions?

Comment: I've just edited my answer, please check out. Edit makes more sense to me about the result..

Comment: one thing that no one addressed yet, and I think is important, is the meaning of the error message. In Octave you can use `:` to use a [default value](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Default-Arguments.html), i.e., `mean(:)` calls Octave using its default value which in the case of `mean` does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a problem in way how you use the `mean()` and `std()` functions and also maybe subscripted assignment is an issue too.

I am not sure but please try these codes below as your function definition:

**1. Row based normalization:**

```
function [X_norm, mu, sigma] = featureNormalize(X)

X_norm = zeros(size(X));
mu     = zeros(1, size(X, 1));
sigma  = zeros(1, size(X, 1));

for x = 1:size(X, 1)
    mu(x)    = mean( X(x, :) );
    sigma(x) = std( X(x, :) );

    for y = 1 : size(X, 2)  
        X_norm(x, y) = ( X(x, y) - mu(x) ) / sigma(x);
    end  
end     
end
```

**2. Column based normalization:**

```
function [X_norm, mu, sigma] = featureNormalize(X)

X_norm = zeros(size(X));
mu     = zeros(1, size(X, 2));
sigma  = zeros(1, size(X, 2));

for y = 1:size(X, 2)
    mu(y)    = mean( X(:, y) );
    sigma(y) = std( X(:, y) );

    for x = 1 : size(X, 1)  
        X_norm(x, y) = ( X(x, y) - mu(y) ) / sigma(y);
    end  
end     
end
```

Comment: You answer correct, but I confused rows and columns)

Comment: @Rocketq - We are confusing about "normalized value for each value by column". How do you want to normalize the matrix, I mean according to what? Taking "mean" and "std" of each rows or columns makes the decision. May you clarify this point?

Comment: Taking by each column, but don't worry  Divakar`s solution is fine

Comment: Thanks for the changes, now the future readers would be less confused! :)

Comment: @Divakar - Exactly! It was a little confusion. I am not sure about future readers, because the question topic seems kinda individual. That's ok. Thank you ((:

Answer (score 2):

If you are calculating normalized values for each element with respect to the `mean` and `sigma` values for each **column**, I think you need to make some changes as your problem code doesn't really reflect that because you are using an array of `mean` and `sigma` values. So, I think you need to do something like this instead -

```
%// Initialize array for final normalized values
X_norm = zeros(size(X));
for x = 1:size(X, 2)

    %// Store mean and standard deviation values for each column
    mu = mean(X(:, x))
    sigma = std(X(:, x))

    %// Use an innermost loop to calculate the normalized values 
    %// for all the elements in each column. 
    %// Thus, for all these elements, you need to use the same mean
    %// and standard deviation calculated in the previous step
    for y = 1:size(X, 1)  
        X_norm(y,x) = (X(y,x) - mu)/sigma
    end  
end
```

You can very easily **vectorize** the above code with **[`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** -

```
X_norm = bsxfun(@rdivide, bsxfun(@minus, X, mean(X,1)),std(X,[],1))
```

Comment: Your solution absolutely right, I confused rows and columns, thank you a lot)

Comment: @Rocketq I think this and [mehmet's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28256008/3293881) would give different results. Given the text of the problem, to me this made more sense, so I have put it this way. Make sure what exactly you are after. To check use something like `X =  rand(5,4)`.